# Difference between @GeneratedValue and @GenericGenerator

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Sometimes I find them together, sometimes alone... other times they seem to do the same.

What's the difference?

Here are three examples. What do they do of different? Why can't I use just @GeneratedValue for all of them?

Example 1

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment") 
Long id;
```

Example 2

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int userId;
```

Example 3

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name="Address",
   joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
)
@GenericGenerator(name="hilo-gen", strategy="hilo")
@CollectionId(columns = @Column(name="Address_id"), generator = "hilo-gen", type = @Type(type="long"))
Collection<Addr> listOfAddresses = new ArrayList<Addr>();
```

Answer (score 91):

When using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) it is often necessary to generate a primary key value.

The `@GeneratedValue` annotation denotes that a value for a column, which must be annotated with `@Id` is generated. The elements `strategy` and `generator` on the annotation describe how the generated value is obtained.

There are four possible values for the `strategy` element on the `@GeneratedValue` annotation: `IDENTITY`, `AUTO`, `TABLE` and `SEQUENCE`.  [See more](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/GenerationType).

So to answer **Part 2** of your question, the code snippet is indicating that the value of `userId` will be obtained through a sequence in the database.

The `generator` element of the `@GeneratedValue` annotation denotes the name of the primary key generator. In **Part1** of your question, the code snippet indicates that a `generator` named `increment` will be used to obtain the primary key value.  `increment` is then defined in the next annotation `@GenericGenerator`.  `@GenericGenerator` is a hibernate annotation used to denote a custom generator, which can be a class or shortcut to a generator supplied by Hibernate.  `increment` is a shortcut to a Hibernate generator that:

> generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only
>   when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not
>   use in a cluster.

In the **Third Part** of your question, the code uses a `hilo` Hibernate generator that:

> uses a hi/lo algorithm to efficiently generate identifiers of type
>   long, short or int, given a table and column (by default
>   hibernate_unique_key and next_hi respectively) as a source of hi
>   values. The hi/lo algorithm generates identifiers that are unique only
>   for a particular database.

Answer (score 18):

*To extend the @kevin-bowersox's answer.*
Relationships between the Hibernate primary key generation strategies and specific generator respectively, as specified in `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory`

```
static {
    GENERATORS.put("uuid", UUIDHexGenerator.class);     // "deprecated" for new use
    GENERATORS.put("hilo", TableHiLoGenerator.class);   // removed in Hibernate 5
    GENERATORS.put("assigned", Assigned.class);
    GENERATORS.put("identity", IdentityGenerator.class);
    GENERATORS.put("select", SelectGenerator.class);
    GENERATORS.put("sequence", SequenceGenerator.class);
    GENERATORS.put("seqhilo", SequenceHiLoGenerator.class);
    GENERATORS.put("increment", IncrementGenerator.class);
    GENERATORS.put("foreign", ForeignGenerator.class);
    GENERATORS.put("guid", GUIDGenerator.class);
    GENERATORS.put("uuid.hex", UUIDHexGenerator.class); // uuid.hex is deprecated
    GENERATORS.put("sequence-identity", SequenceIdentityGenerator.class);
}
```

In Hibernate 4.3 I've found `org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory` class with 3 more strategies:

```java
    register("uuid2", UUIDGenerator.class);
    register("enhanced-sequence", SequenceStyleGenerator.class);
    register("enhanced-table", TableGenerator.class);
```

The above fifteen strategies, plus `native`, are sixteen generation strategies supported in Hibernate by default.

Example with `native`:

```java
@GeneratedValue(generator = "nativeGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "nativeGenerator", strategy = "native")
```

Comment: Just stumbled upon this usage with `"native"` - is there a "safer" way of declaring this strategy? Can't find an enum for it (I'm not a big fan of "magical" strings).

Comment: @Michal I don't know about any. There's always an option to declare a constant by yourself `public static final String NATIVE = "native";`

Comment: I see also that strategy names are hard-coded in Hibernate sources.

Comment: Hello @naXastandswithUkraine, I am also wondering after hibernate 6.2 the GenericGenerator strategy is deprecated. But it is not clear to replace with what ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145708/hibernate-6-2-strategy-deprecated-strategy-enhanced-sequence

Answer (score 11):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Honey")
public class Honey implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
    @Id
    //@SequenceGenerator(name="honeySequence",sequenceName="HONEY_SEQ")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="honeySequence", strategy = "sequence", 
    parameters = { 
            @Parameter(name="sequence", value="HONEY_SEQ") } 
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="honeySequence")
    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private String taste;
```

- @GeneratedValue is used only to get the generated value. The two arguments **strategy** and **generator** are used to define how the value is obtained.
- @GenericGenerator is used to map a user defined sequence generator with your hibernate session.
- You can also use @SequenceGenerator which i have commented in my code. This is not a simple sequence generator but a generator which work on **HILO** algorithm. Due to which you will find a lot of gaps in your sequence, like your first value will start from 50 because the default allocation size is 50.

So its better to use @GenericGenerator for your own architecture. But if you are bound to use @SequenceGenerator you have to manually edit your sequence to have two more attributes **allocationSize=1** and **initialValue=1**. And to work with these attributes you need to add apropert in your [hibernate.cfg.xml](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm) file

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</property>
```

Comment: I know this is an old post. So in your example above, is the sequence "HONEY_SEQ" a sequence created for that table in the actual database (Oracle, DB2 etc...)?

Comment: Yes. HONEY_SEQ is a the name of the database sequence as it is created on the database.

Comment: Hi @cogitoboy, will the "HONEY_SEQ" be created automatically by Hibernate or i need to create it on the database?

Comment: @jumping_monkey, hibernate can't create a seq, you need to create a db seq manually.

Comment: Thanks @MohdFaizanKhan, that was what i was thinking. It never worked until i created it manually. That would be a "nice-to-have" feature though.