# Hibernate session.save() always returning 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm getting a weird result in session.save(). It is always returning 1. but the value in database is inserted correctly. Please suggest anything you found doubtful

**Code**

```
session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
userId = (Long)session.save(user);
transaction.commit();
```

**User - Persistence**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "USERNAME", length = 100)
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 100)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID")
public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

@Column(name = "IMAGEURL", length = 2000)
public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

### Version

Hibernate: 4.3.7 final

Spring: 4.1.2

Answer (score 2):

Referring to this question [Difference between @GeneratedValue and @GenericGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205574/difference-between-generatedvalue-and-genericgenerator).

The problem may be with your `@GeneratedValue`.

So you can change

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

to

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
```

Note : You can refer **[this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-identity-sequence)** to assign your database sequence to @GeneratedValue

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Initially it was the same. I changed to this for trial and error.Again i tried now as you suggested, Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: So the ID value is getting inserted properly in your table?

Comment: Yes, Its properly inserted in my table. But returning wrong value

Comment: When you say its correctly inserting are the ID column values being incremented in the database.Is that column a primary key in table?

Comment: Yes, It is. You can see that @Id there. It's auto increment

Comment: There is a possibility that you define @Id at hibernate and still could have forgotten to define a primary key on your table. So the ID column values in database table User are incrementing on each save and the records are persisted but id value is not correctly returned by the save method?

Comment: Yes, as said by @Balaji, check your table structure.. Is primary key is defined?

Comment: @NamanGala and Balaji The table structure was correct the problem was the onetoOne mapping it was manyToOne So it was restricted to select. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

From the code I see that your generation strategy is Sequence. But you missed to map the sequence to the annotation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="YOUR_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Else if you are using a custom generator then you should have mapped as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator= "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks again for the reply. But it's not working.

Comment: Can you please give me a few more details like: What DB you are using? Are you using a sequence to populate the primary key. Is your transaction succeeding.

Comment: Yeah I got it working the, problem were the onetoOne mapping. Actually it was manytomany. That restricted the result.