# when run multiple times to insert JPA Entity id gives org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ContactGroup implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7161778136151592279L;
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@Column(name = "GRP_ID")
private Long id;
```

}

In my entity id is the primary key when insert the data first time it was running and insert with id 1 and if I run again It will gives error Can you please tell me What did I wrong

Comment: check this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205574/difference-between-generatedvalue-and-genericgenerator

Comment: using non-standard generators, so not JPA. There are ample options in JPA standard for the vast majority of usecases

Answer (score 0):

If you have your table with autoincrement, can use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```