# Hibernate 6.2 strategy deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The hibernate 6.2 depreciated "strategy".
In our current code base we are using

```
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "sequenceGenerator",
        strategy = "enhanced-sequence"
    )
```

However, I am unsure how to replace it with the new approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the enhanced-sequence correspanding class is SequenceStyleGenerator.class
So it should be replace with `type = SequenceStyleGenerator.class`

```
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "sequenceGenerator",
        type = SequenceStyleGenerator.class
    )
```

https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/hibernate-core/blob/7e42b464442d0535d2d1dbb7dc501c8064825d54/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/factory/DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java#L82
[image]